# raising the probability of correct answers of nextItem (catR)

Tags: r, psychometrics, item-response-theory

Using the catR package I am trying to create a nextItem call that respondents would answer correctly about 65% of the time (even if that means the method is not as efficient as it could be). Children often get upset if they only get 50% right.

So I thought to lower the theta estimate used to get nextItem like this:

```
pdiff<- _some_value_
theta<-thetaEst(exposed_parameters, corrects)
nextTheta<-theta-pdiff
nextitem<-nextItem(item_param_tbl, theta=nextTheta)
```

The question is by how much should I lower theta so that respondents would get the choosen item right about 65% of the time?

I ran the following simulation:

```
library('catR')
bank <- genDichoMatrix(items = 500)
n<-500
responses <- data.frame()
thetas <- rnorm(n)
for (i in 1:n) {
  row <- genPattern(th = thetas[i], bank)
  responses<-rbind(responses,row)
}  

means <- data.frame(theta=NA, item=NA, prob=NA)
thetas<-seq(-3, 3, by = 0.1)
for (i in thetas) {
  item<-nextItem(bank, theta = i, criterion='bOpt')[[1]]
  row <- c(i,item,mean(responses[,item]))
  means<-rbind(means,row)
}

fit <- lm(prob ~ theta, data=means)
plot(means$theta,means$prob)
abline(fit)
summary(fit)
```

This suggests that lowering theta by 1 yields a 10% increase in the probability of a correct response, so if I want 65% right I should lower it by 1.5

Is this the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't sound like you need to use the `findItem()` function at all, and instead you could just roll your own. Just compute the expected probability function for positive endorsement given the current $\hat{\theta}$ estimates, $P_i (\hat{\theta}, \psi)$, and select the item which is closes to your desired selection criteria.

For instance, in your case your desired expected item response probability $\pi = .65$, therefore pick the $i$th item from the remaining item pool where $|P_i (\hat{\theta}, \psi) - \pi|$ is the smallest value (or if tied, randomly select an item between the ties). That should give the desired result while still being quasi-adaptive.

Comment: Now I will only need to find out how to get this probability for each item for a given theta during runtime. If you know how to do that I would be grateful for some direction.

Comment: See the `Pi()` function in the package. Also, be sure to up-vote answers you mark as correct for better visibility and support.

Comment: Based on your comment this is what I came up with for getting the 3 best item candidates:
`library(catR)
data(tcals)
N <- 3
P<-0.6
Th<-0
tcals <- as.matrix(tcals[,1:4])
x<-abs(P-Pi(th = Th, tcals)$Pi)
ndx <- order(x)[1:N]
ndx`